# svn log shows all of the logs for changes committed to the trunk, but doesn't show my branch commits

Tags: svn, branch

I'm working on branch of a trunk, and am able to commit changes to my branch.  However, `svn log` shows the log of changes to the trunk.   How do I get a log of changes to my branch only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`svn log --stop-on-copy` in branch's WC

Comment: @Ben - show used command, expected result and received output

Comment: update: if I did an `svn log --stop-on-copy` at the top of the working copy, it does not show the most recent commit.  However, if I point it to the remote branch repository, then it does show the most recent commit.

Comment: @Ben - `svn log` on WC show only revisions, existing in WC. If you are out of sync (not `svn up` WC, but have commits in repo), log output will be different